# How do I breed an apocalypse dragon?

Tags: dragon-city

Ok, so I'm playing dragon city and in the description of an apocalypse dragon, it is noted that it is almost impossible to breed these dragons. Is there a sure fire way of breeding one of these dragons? If so, what two dragons do I need to breed?

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a lot of combinations possible. Its too much work to describe it all, so I'll just post the best combination, and the [link](http://dragoncityguide.net/how-to-breed-apocalypse/) where you can find them all.

The best combination is breeding an Abyss and a Double Nature. That way you have %22.20 chance to get an Apocalypse Dragon.

Comment: Actually it is Archangel plus Abyss with 24.49% chance

Answer (score 0):

Combinations are virtually everywhere. You need a Level 3 Breeding Sanctuary to able to breed an Apocalypse Dragon. According to [Dragon City Wiki](http://dragoncity.wikia.com/wiki/Apocalypse_Dragon), it says:

> The most powerful of the four-elements-dragons, he spells the end of an era! With his combination of four opposite elements, the Apocalypse Dragon is pure destruction – albeit unintentionally. He is so difficult to breed that you may never see one.

Your chance are small but getting that dragon will mean total destruction to your opponents in
both swagger and battling! Keep trying with different combinations to find out. According to the [Dragoncity Guide](http://dragoncityguide.net/how-to-breed-apocalypse/), the top three most likely combinations for successfully this dragon is:

1. Archangel + Abyss - 24.49% Chance, Parents >= Level 9, Sanctuary - Level 7, Expected Time: 77:30:00
2. Double Ice + Abyss - 23.53% Chance, Parents >= Level 9, Sanctuary - Level 7, Expected Time: 75:45:00
3. Dragonfly + Abyss - 23.27% Chance, Parent >= Level 20, Sanctuary - Level 7, Expected Time: 73:07:30

Looks like you really need an Abyss Dragon to get the best bet on the Apocalypse Dragon! At least a Level 7 Breeding Sanctuary, time, and perseverance to get that dragon. I hope you get your Apocalypse Dragon and this answer answers your question!

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible, I just bred one! I bred a dark fire and a cold star dragon in a level 3 breeding sanctuary, it only took my 4-5 tries. I hope I've helped!

Answer (score -1):

Sun and Penguin Should work. But it may take a couple of tries. You should look for a 62 hr breed in your Sanctuary.

Answer (score -1):

You could breed the fallen angel and the cool fire in a level 3 breeding sanctuary.

To get a cool fire, breed the pearl dragon and the firebird dragon.

To get the fallen angel, breed the venom dragon and the sun dragon.

Answer (score -1):

You could breed vampire and cold star dragon at breeding santury lv 5    there is 70 percent chance to get it               REMEMBER   vampire on left and cold star on right

Answer (score -2):

With a Wyvern and Cold Ice Dragon, it will work after around 10 times breeding.

Comment: With wyvern at lv 15 and cold ice lv 10

Answer (score -3):

You could try breeding with "Fallen Angel" and "Cool Fire", there is a 53.23% chance to get it this way.

Repeatedly doing this is a good way to get it.